# wrong in calculationg the SHA 256

Tags: java, hash, sha256

I need to calculate the SHA 256 for my password.

#### i already know that I can user the common codec from apache but this is not allowed in where i am working

I tried to make a simple function to return the sha 256 from a plain text, which is:

```
public static String getSHA1(String plainText) {
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

            md.update(plainText.getBytes());
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < md.digest().length; i++) {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & md.digest()[i]));
            }
            return hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

my problem is whatever the input is, the result is the same. i always got this result

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

I can calculate the sha 256 online using this website http://onlinemd5.com/

but i need to calculate it from my code.

your help is appreciated and lovely.

Comment: Please do not use StringBuffer unless you have to, it was replaced by StringBuilder almost ten years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `digest()`:

> Completes the hash computation by performing final operations such as padding. **The digest is reset after this call is made.**

Call `digest()` once and put the results into a variable.

(By the way, had you searched for the digest, which is always a good idea whenever you get a fixed result, you would have seen that it's the SHA-256 digest for the empty string.)

Comment: Dear Mr. chrylis, thanks for your answer, Would you please check my code. I am using `digest()` in the loop.

Comment: @user3110137 Right. You keep calling it over and over. After you call `md.digest()` the first time to get its length, `md` is reset. Every time you call it after that, you're getting the digest for the empty string.

Comment: Dear Mr. chrylis, Now i got you. You mean that I have to call it just one time and assign the result for a variable, then loop on this variable. I will try it in my code right now. I appreciate your time with me.

Comment: Dear Mr. chrylis, I thank you very much, you are correct. It works, but there is one thing different. my code gives me `a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3` but the online website gives me `A665A45920422F9D417E4867EFDC4FB8A04A1F3FFF1FA07E998E86F7F7A27AE3` they are the same except the capital letters and small letters. is that wrong?

Comment: @user3110137 You're printing out the bytes as hex digits, which aren't case sensitive (they're just treating `A` to `F` like more numbers). If you need one or the other (lowercase is more usual, but there's no important difference), just upper- or lower-case the string, or use a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to print in uppercase.